# Angular with Cordova and Ionic Firebase Auth signInWithPopup throwing an Error on Mobile Devices

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have Implemented Firebase Authentication (Ionic, Angular5 and Cordova) to my application and tested it on the browser, everything is working fine. I am able to login using either google or facebook. I am able as well to put data inside the Firestore Database.

However once deployed on a Mobile Device, In my case an android device I'm getting the following error:

```
{code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment", message: "This operation is not supported in the environment…"}
```

The error seems to be coming from:

```
private oAuthLogin(provider) {
return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((credential) => {
    this.updateUserData(credential.user)
  })
}
```

When signInWithPopup is replaced with signInWithRedirect the error is gone.
However this is not what I need.
I need to be able to open a popup for the user to sign it from and not redirecting him from my application to the browser in order to perform the login process.

Is that possible? ( I see market applications opening a popup for authentication using social media and not redirection)

Thank you

for info I'm using: Angular 4.4.4, AngularFire5, Cordova and Ionic 3 (all latest version)

Comment: Why are you using Angular 5 (RC) already? Ionic3 currently has a peer dependency on Angular 4.4.4.

Comment: Sorry my bad I'm actually using Angular 4.4.4 while AngularFire is actually 5 RC

Comment: How do you expect to open a popup in a mobile app? `signInWithRedirect` in Cordova/Ionic functions like a popup. When you start the flow, it will open a chrome custom tab or SFSafariViewController, etc. This will then close and show the Cordova webview where your app is running.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I do not want, for it to move out of the application! any i achieved that using the GooglePlus plugin mentioned in the comment to David and I was able to show a "popup" for google sign in.

Answer (score 0):

OK according to the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPopup) for the `signInWithPopup()` method your error means the following:

> **auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment**: 
>   Thrown if this operation is not supported in the environment your application is running on. `location.protocol` must be **http** or **https**.

As you are using Ionic the files are served via the `file://` protocol on Android and via a local webserver (`localhost://`) on iOS which means `location.protocol` does not meet the requirements of the library.

This [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/279) contains a lot of proposals on how to work around that limitation in Ionic/Cordova apps. I hope one of them work for you!

Comment: Yeah I checked that github issue as well however they are suggesting using Redirect Method... After extensive search i think that the only solution is to drop this approach and use the native plugins such as https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus If anyone is interested in my question this is the solution I'm going to use

Comment: As the firebase web SDK does not support it a native solution is probably the best approach yes!